# How to remove sass plugin from Nativescript?

Tags: sass, nativescript, nativescript-angular, nativescript-plugin

I did `tns install sass` and now I want to remove it.
I tried `tns plugin remove nativescript-dev-sass` and `tns plugin remove sass` with no success!

How can I get rid of it? It is really annoying me and I don't want to use it.
when I do `tns plugin` I get

```
Dev Dependencies:

nativescript-dev-sass
```

But the command `tns plugin remove nativescript-dev-sass` gives this message: Plugin "nativescript-dev-sass" is not installed.

Or, how can I avoid sass compiler being called when I do `tns run android` ?

Comment: Make sure it is removed from your package.json and also do a search for nativescript-dev-sass.js  in your folder.  I seem to recall the hook file not getting removed.

Comment: It is likely that the hook is not removed. Remove the hooks  dev sass directory yourself.

Comment: Thanks guys, removed the hooks and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
npm uninstall nativescript-dev-sass
```